# Can't find css for datetime module

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

I found I can use this css link:
`https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/core@^1.11.0/dist/blueprint.css` for blueprint. Where do I get the CSS for the `datetime` module from?

It looks like this at the moment: [image]

Comment: probably -> https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/datetime@1.11.0/dist/blueprint-datetime.css

Comment: Probably? How did you know?

Comment: datetime@1.11.0 is the latest version in [blueprintjs repo](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint), so following unpkg syntax `https://unpkg.com/package@version/file` you can get the file you want real quick :p

Answer (score 3):

You must import the correct styles for DateRangeInput

```css
@import "~normalize.css/normalize.css"; 
@import "~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css"; 
@import "~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
@import "~@blueprintjs/datetime/lib/css/blueprint-datetime.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

- i have already these

  ```
  @import "~normalize.css";
  @import "~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
  @import "~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
  ```
- added these css

  ```
  @import "~@blueprintjs/datetime/lib/css/blueprint-datetime.css";
  ```
- date picker working as well

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have trouble with `DatePicker3`<sup>1</sup> - both of these are needed:

```
import "@blueprintjs/datetime/lib/css/blueprint-datetime.css";
import "@blueprintjs/datetime2/lib/css/blueprint-datetime2.css";
```

I made a mistake of including only `blueprint-datetime2.css` and it rendered all wrong until I also included `blueprint-datetime.css`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *From `@blueprintjs/datetime2`, version 2.2.6 as of this writing. The project was based on BlueprintJS v5.*